# Where does Windows keep JDK location reference?

Tags: java, windows, versions

I previously had Java 7 installed on my Windows PC. System environment variable also had location to it. I installed Java 10 without uninstalling 7 or changing the environment variable. Now when I go to CMD or Cygwin and enter Java -version it says Java 10.

I would think since I didn't change the environment variable that it would still be 7. How is Windows deciding what JDK to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Using the Windows Registry. And in cygwin you can type `which java` to find out the location of the binary/script that it invokes.

Comment: Or in Windows CMD `where java` -- but are you asking for actual JDK, or for JRE (including the 'public JRE' component in the JDK installer)? They work differently, and the JRE behavior changed somewhere in mid-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is Windows deciding what JDK to use?

Windows is NOT making decisions on its own. If you get version 10 information when you run `java -version`, it is because Windows is finding the folder containing `java.exe` corresponding to the version 10 first in the paths pointed to by the PATH environment variable. If you have installed Java using an installer, the installer would update the PATH variable for you. Check your PATH variable and you will see the Java 10 folder appearing there first and then Java 7 folder.

Answer (score 4):

Probably your `JAVA_HOME` or just `PATH` environment variables were changed.

Go to command line and do the following to check it:

```
> echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

For example, for me it gives back:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a java ide , you might  find the location in JRE configurations. for example in eclipse :

> windows > preferences > Installed JREs

.

Answer (score 2):

Your JAVA_HOME variable might still be set to JDK 7 directory, however the Java 10 installation may have inserted it's /bin directory to the PATH.

Check to ensure that java 10 isn't on the PATH before java 7, or hasn't overwritten it.

CMD etc. check the path for the binaries for commands like java-version.